# Am I on the right track

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently LeetCoding with python and was stumped on creating an efficient solution to a problem where you have an array of (M X N) so for example `array = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` and it calculates the sum of each inner array and outputs the maximum sum.

I saw this solution but was wondering if I was on the right track to understand what was going on underneath with the built in functions.

Here's my solution:

```
class Solution:
    def maximumWealth(self, accounts: List[List[int]]) -> int:

        count = 0

        for i in accounts:
            count = max(sum(i), count)
        return count

    # I was thinking max does something like this
    # max(sum(i)) = [1+2+3] = 6
    # Then moves on by updating count
    # Then adds the second inner array and determines which one is the max sum
```

This was the LeetCode explanation:
Explanation:
1st customer has wealth = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
2nd customer has wealth = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6

Both customers are considered the richest with a wealth of 6 each, so return 6.

Comment: this code seems alright; you may want to give it different input arrays an play around with it a little to see that it works. what is your question, though?

Comment: @JVod I wanted to know if my interpretation of using the max function along with the sum and counter parameters were correct. I had a quite a hard time understanding what my max function is doing.

Comment: Another solution is simply this: max(map(sum, accounts))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> # max(sum(i)) = [1+2+3] = 6

this is not correct, I'm not sure if it's your typing error.

`i` is each of the array, like `[1, 2, 3]`

`sum(i)` calculates sum of the array, `sum([1, 2, 3])` is 6

`max` the sum with the last max value (`count`), and update it, then `count` is always the max sum of arrays till ending.

Comment: THANK YOU! Yes, I was exactly wondering that. I may have made a typo but I was trying to bring the point across of the sum calculating the sum of all the indexes of that certain inner array.

Comment: for builtin functions, and classes, python doc will help you answer these kind of questions. And I sometimes use `help` func in repl, like typing `help(sum)`, which shows a brief explain for the func.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `map` each inner list to the `sum` function so that you can use the `max` function to obtain the maximum sum:

```
max(map(sum, accounts))
```